# How can I summarize all the pixels from a single raster using Google Earth Engine?

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine

I am trying to summarize all the values from one single raster to get a value (with the total). I ve used this code and I get the total value of the summarize from all the pixels in the region but I don't know how to use that value for other expressions. Could anyone help me?

```js
var image = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC8_L1T/LC80440342014077LGN00')
.select(['B4']);

var region = geometry1

var sumB4 = image.select('B4').reduceRegion({
 reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
 geometry: geometry1,
 scale: 30,
 maxPixels: 1e9
 });
```

The total value is 654789874.465978 and now I need to use this value to introduce in a NDVI formula.

How can I do it?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "now I need to use this value to introduce in a NDVI formula".  Could you better explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the confusion arises from the fact that the return value of the `reduceRegion()` is a Dictionary.  To get the result and do something with it, you need to `get()` the result from the Dictionary:

```js
var image = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC8_L1T/LC80440342014077LGN00')
  .select(['B4']);

// Assumes a geometry object that overlays the image.
var sumB4 = image.select('B4').reduceRegion({
 reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
 geometry: geometry,
 scale: 30,
 maxPixels: 1e9
});

// ee.Dictionary with reducer outputs keyed by bandname.
print(sumB4);
// ee.Number
print(sumB4.get('B4'));
// Do something with the reducer output.
var thing = ee.Image.constant(sumB4.get('B4'));
Map.addLayer(thing);
```

Note that the return value is a [server object](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/client_server), so you must use Earth Engine functions on it.  See [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorial_js_02) for instruction on how to use server-side objects.